# Grep(or alternative) for 2 strings, matching one, another or both are success, contains anything else is a fail

Tags: linux, bash, ksh

I want to analyse output from a command.
I have 2 potential string matches.
If I match one, the other or both, I class that as a pass.
If the output contains anything else I want to flag it as a fail.

This was my original code, which works most of the time.
But when the output(on a rare occasion) contains both my strings, which is allowed. It flags as a fail:

```
 if [ "$STATUS" != "Ok" ] && [ "$STATUS" != "Non-Critical" ]             
   then  
   echo "FAILED: STATUS NOT 'Ok' OR NOT 'Non-Critical'"
   else
   echo " Status check good."
 fi
```

The above fails for me when my output contains both strings, which is not what I want.

So, to be clear:
Ok - On it's own is a pass.

Non-Critical - On it's own is a pass.

Ok
Non-Critical - is a pass.

Non-Critical
Ok - is a pass.

ANYTHING else is a fail

Hoping someone smarter than me can help :-)

Comment: Did you forget a `$` in `"STATUS" != "Non-Critical"`?

Comment: `if I match one` is this a an exact match, or do you want to search if any substring matches?

Comment: I guess the code should work fine if you put a `$` in `"STATUS" != "Non-Critical”` as pointed out by @January

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, I do have the $. I'll correct it if it will let me.

Comment: @Mihir: not really, because STATUS may be "Non-Critical Ok" and then the condition fails.

Comment: @January, i took the question the wrong way i guess.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sed for that.

```
echo -e "Critical\nNon-Critical\nNon-Critical Ok" | 
  sed 's/.*\(Non-Critical\|Ok\).*/PASS/;t;s/.*/FAIL/'
```

Explanation: first we replace "Non-Critical" or "Ok" and everything else on that line by PASS; then, the command `t` jumps to the end of the script upon successful match. If, however, the match is not successful, everything gets replaced by FAIL. Output of the above command:

```
FAIL
PASS
PASS
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a case?

```
case "$STATUS" in
*Non-Critical*) echo PASS;;
          *Ok*) echo PASS;;
             *) echo FAIL;;
esac
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl version

```
echo -e "Critical\nNon-Critical\nNon-Critical Ok" | perl -ne 'print((/Non-Critical|Ok/?PASS:FAIL)."\n")'
FAIL
PASS
PASS
```

For ternary operator `a?b:c` look [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 0):

Also (works only in ksh)

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [[ $STATUS = @(~(+i:*OK*)) || $STATUS = @(~(+i:*Non-Critical*)) ]]; then
        echo "good"
else
        echo "bad"
fi
```

or if you don't want it to be case independant (works both in bash and ksh)

```
if [[ $STATUS = @(*OK*) || $STATUS = @(*Non-Critical*) ]]; then ............
```